# Find integers $p$ and $q$ such that ${\sqrt{5} \over \sqrt{5} - 2} = {p + q\sqrt{5}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My child brought home a problem that I'm stumped with helping them with. It's basically finding integers `p` and `q` such that:

$${\sqrt{5} \over \sqrt{5} - 2} = {p + q\sqrt{5}}$$

The *reason* I'm stumped is because I seem to remember from *many* years ago that you need two distinct equations to solve for two variables. With *one* equation, all you can do is define one variable in terms of the other. Obviously, I can do *that* bit with:

$$p = {\sqrt{5} \over \sqrt{5} - 2} - q\sqrt{5}$$
then further simplifying from there.

However, I'm pretty certain that the fact the solutions are *integers* are meant to limit the solution space somehow but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Any advice would be gratefully accepted. I have no intention passing the *solution* on to my child but, if I could get some information on how to proceed (or even the outright solution should you wish to be generous), I can at least *nudge* them in the right direction.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @paxdiablo I've taken a stab at a more descriptive title.

Comment: Awesome, didn't even realise you could put MathJax in the title. This is *much* better than StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply the fraction by
$$1=\frac{\sqrt{5}+2}{\sqrt{5}+2}.$$

**Full solution:**

Applying the hint shows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
 p+q\sqrt{5}&=&\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}-2}\\
 &=&\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}-2}\frac{\sqrt{5}+2}{\sqrt{5}+2}\\
 &=&\frac{\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{5}+2)}{(\sqrt{5}-2)(\sqrt{5}+2)}\\
 &=&\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}^2-2^2}\\
 &=&5+2\sqrt{5},
 \end{eqnarray*}
and so $p=5$ and $q=2$.

Comment: Ah, excellent. The *instant* I saw from the hint that $${5 + 2\sqrt{5}} = {p + q\sqrt{5}}$$ it all came together. Many thanks.

Comment: And also, $$5+2\sqrt5 =\sqrt5\,\left(\tfrac{1+\sqrt5}2\right)^3$$

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII That's hinting at algebraic number theory though, not so much elementary number theory for a child ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just cross-multiply.

${\sqrt{5} \over \sqrt{5} - 2} = {p + q\sqrt{5}}
$
becomes
$\sqrt{5}
=(\sqrt{5} - 2)(p + q\sqrt{5})
=\sqrt{5}(p-2q)-2p+5q
$.

If $p$ and $q$ are rational,
we must have
$p-2q=1$ and $2p=5q$
so
$5q=2(2q+1)
=4q+2
$
so
$q=2, p=5$.

Check:
$(5+2\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{5}-2)
=\sqrt{5}(\sqrt{5}+2)(\sqrt{5}-2)
=\sqrt{5}
$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply both the numerator and denominator by ${\sqrt{5}}+2$

We get $\frac{\sqrt{5}*(\sqrt{5}+2)}{(\sqrt{5}-2)*(\sqrt{5}+2)}$

Then the denominator can be simplified as $\sqrt{5}\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{5}-2\sqrt{5}-4$

Then, after expanding $\frac{5+2\sqrt{5}}{1}$ is the result

Then we get $p=5, q=2$

Comment: The denominator is $1$ not $3$.

Comment: So sorry about that